# CSS "sticky footer" conflicting with percentage height of nested divs?

Tags: css, height, percentage, sticky-footer, html

I have a "main-section" div that is set to inherit it's height from its' parent div, which is the "wrapper" div. The wrapper div is set to inherit it's height from its' parent div, which is the body of the document. The `html` and `body` tags are set to `height: 100%`.

So, in order to use the CSS "sticky footer" (found at http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/), I have to set `padding-bottom` in the "main-section" div equal to the height of the "footer" div (which has to be **outside** of the wrapper div). Then, the footer div must be given a *negative* `margin-top` value equal to the height of the footer as well.

All of this is working in keeping the footer at the bottom of the page, but I am trying to extend the height of the main-section `100%` to the footer so that the `background-color` of the main-section is visible down the entirity of the page.

I am close in doing this, except the main-section is now extending beyond the footer, and stretching the window beyond 100% height (when there is not enough content to exceed the page height), and the backgroung-color is then visible beyond the footer, beyond the height of the page (which is not desirable).

It seems that the necessary parameter of `padding-bottom` in the main-section div is causing this problem, even though the footer is set to `clear: both` and `position: relative` (which **does** keep the footer at the bottom of the page, but the main-section div is still extending below the footer quite a bit). Or maybe the `min-height: 100%` attribute of the wrapper could be causing a conflict?

Here is the relevant html:

```
<div id="wrap">

    <div id="header">
        ...
    </div> <!-- end of header -->

    <div id="main-section">
        ...
    </div> <!-- end of main section -->

</div> <!-- end of wrapper -->

<div id="footer">
    ...
</div> <!-- end of footer -->
```

...and here is the relevant CSS:

```
*
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}

body
{
    background-color: #bbb;
}

#wrapper
{
    /* wrapper 100% of screen */
        min-height: 100%;

    height: inherit;

    width: 950px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

    #header
    {
        background-color: #C97;
        line-height: auto;
        text-align: center;

        font-family: "Lucida Console";
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 2.5em;
    }

    #main-section
    {
        background-color: #ddd;

        height: inherit;

        /* for a "sticky" footer */
        padding-bottom: 50px; /* equal to the height of the footer */
    }
    #footer
    {       
        clear: both;
        position: relative;

        height: 50px;
        line-height: 50px;
        margin-top: -50px; /* equal to the height of the footer, for a "sticky footer" */

        width: 950px; /* equal to width of wrapper */

        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;

        text-align: center;

        background-color: #C97;
    }
```

---

**EDIT**:  It is important to mention that I am testing this in Firefox.

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, a workaround, that exhibits the same behavior --

Instead of messing with the nested main-section div, I am applying the `background-color` to the wrapper div itself (and also not applying `postion: absolute` to the main-section div, but still applying `position: fixed` to the footer div).

This way, the main-section can contain any amount of content, and it will appear to have a 100% height background-color.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://dtusarview.wordpress.com/2012/06/23/sticky-headerfooter-like-facebook/) is a reference for you.

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/F6dez/)

Comment: That's pretty cool, thanks for the info @tusar. This is giving me some interesting ideas -- I'd like to make a page with a sticky header that appears `onmouseover`, disappears `onmouseout`, and with some jQuery animation (I bet there is a jQuery solution for this).

Answer (score 0):

Make change in footer

```
#footer
{       
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    position:fixed;  // this is the key
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    width: 950px;
    background-color: #C97;
}​
```

**[Updated Jsfiidle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zkd2E/6/)**

Comment: Thank you for the help @Wasim, but in your example the `background-color` of the main-section div is not extending to the footer, to the full height of the page... that's what I'm stuck on.

Comment: Hmm, ok ok, thanks @Wasim, so does this have to do with setting the main-section div to `position: absolute` and the footer div to `position: fixed`? I can see that it is working in your example, but I am having trouble modifying my code to reflect the same changes..

Comment: I just came up with a workaround, that exhibits the same behavior -- instead of messing with the nested main-section div, I am applying the background-color to the wrapper itself (and also not applying `postion: absolute` to the main-section, but still applying `position: fixed` to the footer). This way, the main-section can contain any amount of content, and it will appear to have a 100% height background-color.